Can laws of nature cause something or limit something? Can laws be Necessary existent?
Can Laws of nature cause something or restrict something? And according to contingency argument what would be the case of laws of nature being necessary existent? Lastly can laws exists, without a nature?

I think you've misunderstood the laws of nature. They are a set of observations / descriptions, not edicts. Nature is, what nature does, not what scientists say is possible. And laws by themselves have no direct causative power. Thye are something written in books.

@Weather Vane You right sir, I don't know much about them but I wanna learn what those represent and able to do.

They represent our (limited) understanding of nature. They can be used to make approximate predictions of what will happen in the future (or roughly 'explain' what happened in the past) but of themselves, the laws have no direct ability. Their influence on how nature behaves is zero!

One area in which our understanding and laws are deficient is in weather forecasting. I hear a hubris-laden scientist exclaim "But it should have rained!" Or in another area "That spider does not have enough brain cells to do that!" When it did rain and the spider did do the unexpected. Did they break the laws of nature? Absolutely not.
